# Internet Explorer blocks redirects?

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer

Lately I've had a problem of Internet Explorer "blocking" redirects.

It has worked before, but suddenly IE started causing problems.

In my CMS, I can do redirects (header location in PHP), for example when a page doesn't exists, it can redirect to the front page. Also if the slug URL is incorrect, it will redirect to the correct slug.

Only problem is, that if there is TWO redirects in a row, Internet Explorer just dies with a 404 (or 500, dont remember).

Works fine in Chrome and Firefox with no problem.

Have anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: can you provide an example? which IE version(s) are we talking about?

Comment: you should make a small example, 2 files with as little as possible code (just the 2 redirects) that has this problem. You will probably find before you've accomplished that that it does work in your mini-case, and some other bug is going on, but if you don't, we can use the code to recreate the bug on our systems, to see what's going on.

Comment: http://goo.gl/icvTd check this link in both Chrome and IE. IE says 'Cannot display the webpage' but Chrome shows it just fine?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good rule of thumb to place exit; after all redirects.

```
header('Location: mypage.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! By some odd reason, the CMS inserted a 301 header, but did not redirect. Chrome apparently show the page even when it has received a 301 header, but IE just stops parsing the page.